# Angular negative valuechanges return bool value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I want to toggle between single checkbox(DOList) against multiple checkboxes(DOWList)

```
this.form.get('DOList').valueChanges.subscribe((bool) => {
        console.log(bool) //
        this.form.get('DOWList').patchValue(Array(this.DOWList.length).fill(bool), {           
            emitEvent: false,
          });
      });
```

Here, bool returns `[false]` if DOList is unchecked and `[true]` if checked. I want to reverse the bool
value within `fill(bool)` method to toggle `DOWList` & `DOList`

Tried by negating bool something like `fill(!bool)`

```
this.form.get('DOList').valueChanges.subscribe((bool) => {
        console.log(bool) //
        this.form.get('DOWList').patchValue(Array(this.DOWList.length).fill(!bool), {           
            emitEvent: false,
          });
      });
```

Comment: And what is the problem? If you need the reversed value in the end, do it in the submit method like: const test = myform.value; test.DOList = !test.DoList; as example.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question, which I resolved using `map`

```
this.form.get('DOList').valueChanges.subscribe((bool) => {
        console.log(bool) //
        this.form.get('DOWList').patchValue(Array(this.DOWList.length).fill(bool).map((bool) => !bool), {           
            emitEvent: false,
          });
      });
```